# How to reformat code associative array in new line in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Simply, I have now code like following:

```
$myArray = array( 'restaurant_id' => $res_id, 'menu_id' => $menu_id, 'food_id' => $foods_id);
```

After reformatting my array is show in one line. If array is long it is time wasting to navigate right side of the editor.

I want to reformat all of my code array snippet like following:

```
$myArray = array(
   'restaurant_id' => $res_id, 
   'menu_id' => $menu_id, 
   'food_id' => $foods_id);
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Simply use your IDE!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally! I found the problem. In `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Wrapping and Braces | Array Initializer` Option was do not wrap.
For that reformat code was not working as expected.

Comment: I even didn't know that I could click on the "do not wrap" ;-)
I replaced it for the "Chop down if long" !  Peeeerfect !

Answer (score 0):

Phpstorm | Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces | Array Initializer
change "Do not wrap" to "Chop down if long"

Answer (score 0):

In phpstorm 2023.2.4 you can find it here:

```
  Settings
    > code style 
     > your language(PHP in my case)(1) 
       > Wrapping and braces (2)
         > Array Initializer (3)
```

Change Array initializer to *wrap always*.
Then select options to your preferences below that.

[image: Showing the settings dialog]

Answer (score -8):

The solution very simple. here i give you two methods. you problem will solve.

1. just simply press "Ctrl+U".
2. Right click on browser and select "View page source".